# cannot parse same xml file again. Android XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

At the 1st time I've parsed XML successfully. Here's code:

```
XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.antennas);
    try
    {
        int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();

        boolean requiredVendorLabel = false;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equals("vendor"))
            {
                if(xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(0).equals(newVendor.toString())) {

                    requiredVendorLabel = true;
                }
                else {
                    requiredVendorLabel = false;
                }
            }
            if(requiredVendorLabel && eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equals("model"))
            {
                antennas.add(xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(0));
            }

            eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot load file for parsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

Then I tried to parse the same file again with the same code. But I've got nothing. While loop processed only once and finished. xmlPullParse.getLineNumber returned (-1), but I supposed than it should returned number greater than zero.

What should I do to parse xml file again?

Comment: Add a log in your catch block. Not sure where this is being executed, but you may not be seeing the toast.

Comment: at the second attempt to parse I've got nullPointerExeption, but at the 1st attempt everything is OK. What is wrong???

Comment: I've found my error. I've forgotten                              eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG in if-block at the 2nd case